# ToDo список на jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго всем времени  суток!

Есть ToDo список на jQuery. В нем есть элементы, но они статические (изменять и добавлять новые можно только через редактирование кода). Естественно, что нужно сделать функцию добавления новых элементов.

Написал код, копирующий определенные строки кода друг за другом, используя `.after()`, но проблема в том, что он добавлял сам элемент списка вверх списка, а кнопки - вниз, причем через раз.

Пробовал так же при помощи `.load()` реализовать что-то подобное, однако это тоже не вышло.

Фрагмент кода JS:

```
<script>
// Waiting for the document to load
    $(document).ready(function() {
// Wanted to create a dynamic item list, that's why I used this variable. I thought it would
// generate unique IDs (there was 'id++' somewhere in the function I already deleted).
        var id = 1;

// This is going to be used as an action for 'Add Item' button. (It is not a button, actually, it is just <span> with cursor: pointer. Using <a> causes page reload);
        $('.add').click(function() {
            $('#item'+id).after(function(i) { // '#item'+id should be something like this in the code: #item2, #item3, etc.

            })
        })

// 'Done' button
        $('#done1').click(function() {
            console.log('# "Done" button pressed');
            $('#list1').css('background-color','#89f49a').css('border','1px solid #16bf31').css('text-decoration','line-through').css('color','#817f7f').css('font-weight','normal');
            console.log('# Item doned successfully');
        });

// 'Undone' button (is gonna be renamed to 'Reset');
        $('#undone1').click(function() {
            console.log('# "Undone" button pressed');
            $('#list1').css('background-color','').css('border','').css('text-decoration','').css('color','').css('font-weight','normal');
        });

// 'Working' button
        $('#working1').click(function() {
            $('#list1').css('background-color','#edc951').css('border','1px solid #dda119').css('font-weight','bold').css('color','#000').css('text-decoration','none');
        });

// 'Cancel' button
        $('#cancel1').click(function() {
            $('#list1').css('background-color','#ff8c8c').css('border','1px solid #ea2c2c').css('font-weight','normal').css('text-decoration','line-through').css('color','#f00');
        });
// 'Delete' button
        $('#del1').click(function() {
            $('div#dlist1').remove();
            $('li#action1').remove();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Фрагмент кода на HTML (часть, где реализованы сам список):

```
<div class="list">
                    <ul id="sortable">
                        <div class="list-item" id="item1"><div class="spacer1" id="spacer1"></div>
                        <div class="l-element" id="dlist1"><li id="list1" class="ui-widget ui-state-default">Create add feature</div>
                        <li id="action1" class="action"><input type="button" value="Done" class="done" id="done1"><input type="button" value="Undone" class="undone" id="undone1"><input type="button" value="Working" class="working" id="working1"><input type="button" value="Cancel" class="cancel" id="cancel1"><span id="del1" class="delete">Delete</span></li>
                        <div class="spacer"></div></div>
                    </ul>
                <div>
```

Собственно, вопрос следующий: как мне реализовать копирование элемента списка, начиная от  `<div class="list">` и заканчивая его же `</div>`?

(комменты писал на английском, если кому непонятно - переведу с радостью :)).

Версия самого проекта: [strasbourgmeetings.org/ccc](http://www.strasbourgmeetings.org/ccc)

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

доброго времени суток. функцией [.clone()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: Точно! Забыл совсем про .clone(). Ступил немного 

Но это, к сожалению, не конечная проблема - теперь для созданных элементов не работаю кнопки. Логично, ведь, они привязаны к id. запись типа

$('#undone1').click(function() {
            console.log('# "Undone" button pressed');
            $('#list' + id).css('background-color','').css('border','').css('text-decoration','').css('color','').css('font-weight','normal');
        });

проблему не решает. Как я полагаю , это из-за того, что он добавляет конечный id. Но суть в том, что даже в самом последнем добавленном элементе это не работает.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что у вас функция click(), которая находится в document ready. Попробуйте через live, или bind.

Comment: Вы хотели сказать, через .on() и .delegate(), верно?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы на Вашем месте посмотрел в сторону [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org). Слишком уж Ваша задача похожа на типовые ангулярские.